# Install app on iOS without Apple Developer Program (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios9, xcode7

On June 8th, Apple announced that with Xcode 7, everyone would be able to install any apps they develop on their devices without an Apple Developer Program Certificate. The Apple Developer website says you only need to log in with your Apple ID. I already did that on Xcode, but every time I try to run an app on my iPad, this happens:

[image: Xcode error]

I've been looking through the Apple Developer website on any instructions on how to do this, but I have not found anything. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't getting a dialog offering to fix the problem?

Comment: here is step you may follow to run application without enrolling developer program : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30885089/3400991

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've previously enrolled in the Safari Developer Program you may find yourself to be an 'Agent' (see your account in Xcode preferences to verify this).

Try logging in with another account, never used for development - create one if you must. Then you will appear as 'Free' and you will be able to fix all issues and finally install your app to your iOS Device.

Comment: Ooh, this might be it. I was enrolled in the Safari Developer Program. Apple has told me that it ends on July 8th. Is there any way to end it prematurely so that I can use my regular Apple ID? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't really find anything in the support pages about it right now. You're better off a the new account - it does not really matter. You'll save your time searching around what is probably not implemented yet. Keep in mind that if you actually develop Safari extensions, you have until July 8th to sign them for free - you don't wanna throw that away.

Answer (score 3):

First Of All, you must have a valid Apple Developer Account.
But no need to add device UDID in developer a/c for install the app on the device.
Follow below steps achieve above:

1) Install Xcode 7

2) Give a unique bundle identifier(Any unique identifier)
[image: edit bundle identifier]

3) Select a valid team from "Team" option. (You can add account from Xcode preferences or there is an option for adding account)
[image]

4)Then Click on fix issue. It will take some time and will be resolved. (If you are getting any error, then there may be some issue with your Apple developer a/c).

5)If you are not getting any kind of error after Click on "Fix issue", then your set up is success.

[image]

6) Now connect your device. Run your Code on Xcode 7 by selecting the destination as your connected device name.

Hopefully it works for all. I have tried in Xcode 7 beta version.
Good Luck and Enjoy....

Comment: Which tools xcode uses to fix the issue? I want to add UDID to local provisioning profile manually without connecting device, but knowing its identifier.