# Xcode: getting a message when trying to run an app on my device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new to ios development.

I am using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4.1, when I'm trying to run my app on
my device I get this message from xcode:

> No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

And when clicking "Fix issue" it suggesting me to enrol Apple's dev program.
by the way I had it once and now it outdated, so how can I over come this problem and run the app without enrolling again?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak or the associated Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember you need to pay for the account, and if yes

[image]

click on this then select **General** then **Identity** then select your iOS development account in the **Team** section. Finally re-run your project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Xcode 6 :D you "need" to enroll apple developer Program to debug at iPhone / Ipad devices if want use this Xcode, but if you download Xcode 7 you can run at your device!!!

So if you want use for now Xcode 6 you only can use emulator, otherwise download Xcode 7 :)

If need any help look at this post : [How to debug at Device using Xcode 7 without enroll apple developer program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735942/install-app-on-ios-without-apple-developer-program-xcode-7)