# Is there a way to create an GPL licensed iOS App and distribute it to customers without violating any license terms?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

I want to create an iOS app using a GPL library, therefore, I will publish the app as open source under GPL license too.
But how can I distribute it to arbitrary customers?

- App Store: Restricts distribution violates GPL.
- B2B: Restricts distribution violates GPL.
- ad Hoc: Manually add every UDID necessary, 100 devices max, restricts distribution violates GPL.
- Enterprise deployment: Would be necessary to create an Enterprise Developer Account for each customer or would violate apple terms of service. [iOS App deployment without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301361/ios-app-deployment-without-appstore)

Article from the FSF about the conflict between the GPL and Apple's terms of service: https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement

So is there anyway, or not possible?

Comment: Hey, I clarified my question, my intention is to set the app under GPL too. I added an article of the FSF about the conflict between the GPL and Apple's terms of service: https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement

Comment: It seems like you have probably answered your own question, but you need a lawyer, not Stack Overflow.  The only way to be sure is not to use GPL code. Look for an MIT licensed alternative or write your own code

Comment: You could possibly provide the source code to each customer and leave it up to them to compile and distribute the solution under an Enterprise membership

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming one. You may be able to get help on the [opensource.se] Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That FSF article is from 2010. Apple's terms have changed a lot in the 8 years before you posted the question.