# Is there another way to release an iOS app other than the Apple store?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia

My AR APP was rejected by Apple for "Usefulness of the AR APP is limited by the minimal features or content it includes" They seem to want me to use AR kit but it's not supported on Unity. I used Vuforia. They were very vague and I'm at max size for the APP right now. Reworking it for my deadline adding interactivity isn't an option. Can I release it without Apple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS App deployment without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301361/ios-app-deployment-without-appstore)

Answer (score 0):

Well its sad to hear this,but you cant
You need XCode to publish it or even test it,but you can build it on Unity,in player settings you can even set certificate and Apple ID but for you to test it,it has to be Mac

Also you can't use Hackintosh as XCode doesn't work on Hackintosh.
Sorry but it is what it is

Comment: Xcode definitely works on PCs, runnig macOS, so called "Hackintosh"